# When and why did garum disappear?

Tags: ancient-rome, food, mediterranean

[Garum or liquamen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garum) was, apparently, extremely popular in classical Rome, consumed by rich and poor on a daily basis, almost on par with bread. It was also known to other Mediterranean civilizations. Alas, this dish is extinct now.

When and why did it disappear? It's as if fishing stopped with the fall of the Empire.

Comment: given the existence of colatura di alici, the production of which dates to the middle ages, when garum was still being produced in the East, are you sure that it ever disappeared from Europe?

Comment: @Tristan, the answers by Lars Bosteen and Jos convinced me that equivalents of garum re-appeared in Europe at least when Thai and Vietnamese restaurants were opened there.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Garum production and consumption declined because increasing instability in the late Western Empire disrupted production and trade (and not just of garum). Further, a key ingredient - salt - became too expensive and pirates undermined the trade routes. Note also that garum was far from the only thing that declined or disappeared along with the empire; so too did many other features of everyday Roman life.  However, it could still be found centuries after the fall of the Western Empire, especially in the Eastern Mediterranean.

---

**Details**

According to the Italian archaeologist Claudio Giardino of the University of Salento (Lecce),

> "In the Roman times, salt was a cheap material....When the Roman
> Empire collapsed, they put taxes on the salt. And because of these
> taxes, it became difficult to produce garum."

*Cited in '[Fish Sauce: An Ancient Roman Condiment Rises Again](https://www.npr.org/sections/thesalt/2013/10/26/240237774/fish-sauce-an-ancient-roman-condiment-rises-again)'*

Also, as the Romans lost control of the Mediterranean, piracy increased:

> "The pirates started destroying the cities and the industries nearby
> the coast. You could be killed any moment by the pirates, without the
> protection of the Romans,"

In order for garum to be produced profitably in large quantities but at prices which most people could afford,

> ...large fishing fleets were essential and so were beachfront
> facilities (especially after regulations were put in place by
> Constantine Harmenopoulus that garum works could not be within a
> certain distance of a town due to the odors) and safe shipping routes
> from areas of production to faraway clients.  Other factors that may
> have affected garum pricing and access were the   requirement of a
> large workforce, land for facilities, and credit during  a tumultuous
> time where shipping routes would not necessarily be secure.  The
> Empire’s decline and the contraction of the Empire pulled apart the
> trade routes and threads from production to the client.

*Source: T. Carpenter & G. Stern, '[The Rise, Fall, and Rise Again of Garum](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/340105043_The_Rise_Fall_and_Rise_Again_of_Garum_Northern_Great_Plains_History_Conference)'. Paper presented at the Northern Great Plains History Conference, September 2016.*

The location of garum production sites away from cities may have meant that, in some cases at least, they were less well-protected from raiders than they would have been had they been located inside walled cities. With this "loss of order", it was not just garum consumption that declined with the decline of the empire; so too did other industries, as well as other features of Roman life, like the construction of roads and

> making a daily visit to the public baths or wearing the toga.

*Source: Carpenter & Stern*

The spread of the popularity of garum to provinces such as Gaul had occurred with the Romanization of these provinces when Italians settled there:

> Augustus settled many Italians in  the  provinces in the settlements
> of the 20s BC. One mostly overlooked way they Romanized the
> provinces, besides recreating grid-pattern Roman cities with baths and
> a forum, was to bring their tongues with them, meaning both the
> speaking of Latin – on which much has been said and written before –
> but also the taste for Roman food.  They imported and eventually
> produced their own garum to enjoy the flavors of home far from Italy.

As the Romans withdrew, so declined the popularity of garum and the expertise to make it. The fact that it did not immediately disappear is an indication of a degree of Romanization among the indigenous population.

Concerning the decline of the trade and consumption of high-priced garum, another factor to consider is the general decline in wealth in mainland Italy especially. The high-priced variety often came from afar as

> Some distantly-made garum was a status symbol (like Belgian beer or
> champagne today).

*Source: Carpenter & Stern*

However, it did not completely disappear with the fall of the Western empire in some regions. [For example](https://www.npr.org/sections/thesalt/2013/10/26/240237774/fish-sauce-an-ancient-roman-condiment-rises-again),

> ...it remained in a few little pockets — like in Southwest Italy,
> where they produce *colatura di alici*, a modern descendant of the
> ancient fish sauce. The product was barely known even in Italy just a
> few years ago, but it is gradually being rediscovered.

Also, [manufacture and consumption continued](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=mPS0tH02IDUC&pg=PA299&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) for a while in Tunisia and Gaul (despite the physician [Anthimus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthimus_(physician)) writing it should be 'banned from every culinary role'), and in the Eastern Mediterranean as late as the 16th century.

There is some controversy as whether Asian garum (the production of which " has been uninterrupted for centuries") was a 'technology transfer' from the west as the origins of the product in Asia are somewhat obscure. Without lending any support to to the 'West-to-East' theory, Carpenter & Stern note that

> Roman and Vietnamese fish sauce have a similar ratio of fish to salt ≤
> 5:1, but the Romans fermented garum for less time before bottling it.
> Both Roman and Southeast Asian cuisines use fish sauce in similar
> manners, as  both  an ingredient in cooking and as a condiment that
> can be diluted with other ingredients like vinegar or sweetener.

Fish sauce remains popular in Asia and is now also found in West African cuisine (where I first encountered it).

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pissalat & Worcestershiresauce (original; although said to be a re-import from India—well, or a local woman!) come to mind?

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain? As always, I'm open to constructive criticism.

Comment: Not me, but how about this? `As the Roman's withdrew` - greengrocer's apostrophe.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Ah, typos...and also 'cities' instead of 'sites' Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Now that a short A is there (why not emph the diff between disappeared & declined more clearly), I'd miss two things: _how much_ did other 'way of life things' disappear _alongside,_ and since this is about taste: how much was the _demand side_ affected (the "popularity" is underexplored), as taste is culturally over-formed and '_we_ don't eat…' might play a role. May be hard to come by, but are are there 'Barbarians from the North' (orwotnot) that just said 'not our thing this juck' ('too strong'/strange or _not enough_ Surstrømming-like…)?

Comment: @LаngLаngС These are all good points that you make but if I follow up on them, I fear that I will end up with a book! On disappeared & declined, my impression is that this is probably unanswerable, though I would postulate that disappeared happened far more rapidly outside of Italy in areas abandoned by the Romans. For Byzantium / Greece, we have to consider also that the Greeks used fish sauce 'independently' of the Romans so that muddies the waters somewhat. On the 'not our thing', there may well be evidence but it's likely to be very anecdotal. Still, might be worth having a look for that.

Answer (score 10):

> Alas, this dish is extinct now.

I don't know when & why garum disappeared. But I do know it is widely used, be it in a different part of the world. Garum is highly popular in Asia. It's widely used a.o. in Thailand, where it is made and sold as [pla ra](http://simplethaifood.com/ingredients/salty-fermented-fish/) (ปลาร้า). The Vietnamese like it too, as do other Asian cultures. *Yes, it still stinks to the skies.*

If you want to try it, go to a shop specialized in Thai or Vietnamese products.

- https://www.templeofthai.com/food/sauces/namplarah-5110000509.php
- https://culinarylore.com/specialty-foods:nam-pla-thai-fermented-fish-sauce/

Comment: +1 You can't make real Pad Thai without fish sauce.

Comment: I'm not sure it's fair to treat all fish sauce as equal. There's differences between modern fish sauces and the one that would have called garum (rough recipes can be found) but on that note, garum is primitive in comparison and the contemporary stuff find in Asian grocery stores would be pretty much always preferred.

Comment: @BooleanCheese Modern Pla Ra has at least one thing in common with garum: it stinks equally bad. Garum was noted for its distinct <barf>"aroma"</barf>.

Comment: Wot? Properly finished _garum_ _doesn't stink!_ Albeit, 'nose of the beholder': It smells _lightly_ fishy, earthy, herbal. During production it's mind numbing. But with all smells as well: even then does the dosage make the poison. (Take scatol, characteristically making shit smell how it does, but in dilution smells like roses and is hence used in perfume!)

Comment: @LаngLаngС I have no idea how garum smells. From what I've read, rather "aromatic" in a very negative way. Thai & Vietnamese fermented fish sauces are made roughly the same as garum. They stink beyond belief. I'm inclined to think garum therefore smell somewhat more than lightly fishy.

Comment: Tasty re-'enactors': https://www.smithsonianmag.com/arts-culture/recoving-the-recipe-for-garum-180978846/